# How to speak with one script to discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a Discord bot that can't really do much at the moment, but that's about to change. I want the bot to write a DM to a certain user with an ID that comes from another script. So script 1 does a task, gets returned so to speak a Discord name/tag and an ID and to this name a DM with the respective ID should be written. Does anyone have an example code for me?

Comment: So, do you intend to have two separate bots, or will these be incorporated in the same source file?  Will your "another script" be triggered from the bot?  There are many ways for your bot to run a subprocess and capture the output, if that's the model.

Comment: Hey, my bot is one script. He should get a string or list with 2 arguments from another normal python script

Comment: Then doesn't just "import your_script" work?